# Is there a way to treat two Postgres tables as one?

Tags: postgresql

I want to select all rows from two tables that have the same number of columns where the columns have the same name and type.

e.g. table 2 is basically a continuation of table 1 and so I want any queries to look through both tables to find the best match.

How would I do that since SELECT would normally just add the second table's columns to the first table.

Comment: do you mean table2 are more columns for table1 or more rows?

Comment: You probably looking for [**partitioning**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Comment: Tabel 2 is more rows. But @Lukasz answered it -- Union.

Comment: Having data split between two tables might be a bad idea. Maybe it is fine -- you might have good reasons for doing it this way. But if (for example) you are trying to keep recent data in one table and older data in another table, it might be a bad idea. Unless you have many many columns and many many millions of rows, I doubt there would be significant performance advantages to having the tables split. On the contrary, performance should suffer if you have to perform UNION every time. You might consider merging the tables. You might also look into adding indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. For `SELECT` only you could use compound query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
UNION ALL
SELEECT *
FROM tab2;
```

or create view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM tab1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM tab2;

SELECT * FROM my_view;
```